# String substitution in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of names and I loop through them to create a comma separated list in a string variable (Bob, George, Will, Terry).

I need the list to eventually look like (Bob, George, Will and Terry).

How do I find the LAST instance of the comma and replace it with the word "and"?  Once I find the LAST instance, I think it's a simple matter of doing something like

```
string new=ori.Substring(0,start) + rep + ori.Substring(start+rep.Length);
```

Thoughts?  Comments?  Suggestions?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: First and most importantly, use the Oxford comma.  And you can use the string function `LastIndexOf` to find the index of the last comma.

Comment: I would suggest reading [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: When u loop through, u will have index number that is increased 1 in each loop. If current index number is equal to (Array list size - 1), it is the last element. I mean current index in the loop is 1 lesser than size of Array or list. Hope u got an idea.

Comment: I question why you first build a string that you then have to parse to modify.  Why not build the second string correctly while you're building the first?

Comment: @adv12, when I build the original string, I do not know how many elements there will be.  Do you have a suggestion for determining the number of elements in a list before the list is complete?

Comment: @RLoomas, I think typically in such a situation you'd accumulate the individual strings in a List<string> or somesuch and then generate the final string when you've got the complete list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you. Added the alternative comma style as well.

```
var names = "Bob, George, Will, Terry";
var lastCommaPosition = names.LastIndexOf(',');
if (lastCommaPosition != -1) 
{
    names = names.Remove(lastCommaPosition, 1)
               //.Insert(lastComma, " and");
                 .Insert(lastCommaPosition, ", and");
}

Console.WriteLine(names);
```

Comment: Thanks, and I like the alternative comma style as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

```
var foo = "Bob, George, Will, Terry";
if (foo.Contains(",")) {
    foo = foo.Substring(0, foo.LastIndexOf(",")) + " and" + foo.Substring(foo.LastIndexOf(",")+ 1);
}
```

Comment: When I added the line above, I get the following error...
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Comment: This is likely the case when you string does not have a comma.  You need to check for a comma, otherwise the `LastIndexOf` will return -1.  I updated the example above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of LINQ and `String.Join`. This solution does not need the last index of a comma and is "more fluent" to read.

```
var list = new List<string> { "Bob", "George", "Will", "Terry" };
var listAsString = list.Count > 1 
        ? string.Join(", ", list.Take(list.Count - 1)) + " and " + list.Last()
        : list.First();
```

Comment: Looks a bit crappy for list length `1`

Comment: @grek40 - You are right; I have edited the code to check for the length of the list.

Comment: Go ahead and check for length `0` as well or the call to `First()` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq,

```
list.Select(i => i).Aggregate((i, j) => i + (list.IndexOf(j) == list.Count -1 ? " and "  :  " , ") + j);
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you wanted to do, but the following code works:

```
string original = "(Bob, George, Will, Terry)";
            string result = "";
            string[] splited = original.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < splited.Count(); i++)
            {
                if(i == splited.Count() - 2)
                {
                    result += splited[i] + " and";
                }
                else if(i == splited.Count() - 1)
                {
                    result += splited[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    result += splited[i] + ",";
                }
            }
```

I Used split to split the original string in a vector so i worked with this vector to replace the last comma to the word "and".